# Internet calendar not updating

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

I have update several machines from Office 2010 to Office 2013. In office 2010 Internet Calendar was working fine, but in 2013 the calendars do show  but they are not updated.

They calendars are no longer in the Account Settings / Internet Calendars. Adding the calendars there again doesn't solve the problem.

Is there a way to make Outlook work again with calendars after the upgrade?